# Why a closed unbounded operator with compact resolvent has its spectrum consisting of eigenvalues with finite multiplicity?

Tags: spectral-theory

Could someone tell me (or has a reference) why a closed unbounded operator with compact resolvent has its spectrum consisting of a sequence of complex eigenvalues, each with finite multiplicity?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the eigenvectors of the original operator are among the eigenvectors of the resolvent.